# Getting refs to rendered videos in FlatList

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-flatlist

I have an application where I am rendering a video component using `expo-video-player` via FlatList as this list could grow in the future and I want to keep things optimized as possible.

What I want to accomplish is that when I click to play on one video in the list, all others will pause if they are playing.  I'm using all functional components and typically if it wasn't in a FlatList could reference a video with the following:

```
const videoRef = useRef(null);

...

<Video 
   ref={videoRef}
   ...
/>
```

and then call `videoRef.current.pauseAsync()` to pause it somewhere else in my code.

However, now that it is in a FlatList I am having trouble understanding how to link the ref for each video and be able to get the ref back to call `pauseAsync()` on the previous video that is playing.

Any direction/guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You prob need to create an Array of Refs.

Something like this:

```js
const videoRefs = [];

const videos = ['url.com/xyz.mp4', 'url.com/abc.mp4'];

videos.forEach((video, index) => {
  videoRefs.push(useRef(null));
});

...

renderItem = ({item, index}) => {
  <Video 
     ref={videoRefs[index]}
     ...
  />
}
```

Comment: Had to alter some code a little bit for my use case but this put me on exactly the right track.  Thank you!

Comment: Good job, SKeney!

Comment: Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Comment: @AhmedElsayed This error usually means that you're calling a hook inside a class component instead in a function component.

Comment: this doesn't work good